# Window.Left is wrong when moving a maximized Window with Windows + Shift + Arrow Keys

Tags: c#, wpf

I encountered a problem in WPF (C#), I need to position a popup on a certain point within the parent window.
I get the parent position with `Application.Current.MainWindow.Left` and `Application.Current.MainWindow.Top`, it works as long as I don't move the window from one monitor to the other with the Windows shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>◄</kbd>/<kbd>►</kbd>. If I use the shortcut the properties stay the same as they were before moving the window.

The window has to be `WindowState.Maximized`, it works if it is not maximized.

I also tried using `Window.GetWindow(this)` instead of `Application.Current.MainWindow`, result is the same.

It seems as if the positionchanged event doesn't occur for the `Application.Current.MainWindow` and it doesn't update the `Left` and `Top` properties.

I didn't find anything on this on SO or Google.
A workaround, hint or solution are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the `Windows + Shift + Cursor Left/Right` shortcut, do you mean `Windows + Shift + Left/Right arrow`? Also I cant' reproduce the issue when using this shortcut. Maybe your `Application.Current.MainWindow` is not set to the correct `Window`?

Comment: yes I mean the arrow keys, my bad. It is the correct window, if I drag and drop with the mouse it changes the Left as expected.

Comment: Can you please create a new empty WPF application and replace the default constructor of your `MainWindow` with the following debug code: ``public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            async Task Test() {
                while (true) {
                    Console.WriteLine((Left, Top));
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                }
            };
            Test();
        }``. It displays the current location of the `Window` in the output window and it works for me even when using the shortcut. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I reproduced the error with your test scenario, the problem only occurs when the WindowState is Maximized.

Comment: Try to use __actualLeft_ and __actualTop_ fields. The code for this particular case  can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600874/window-actualtop-actualleft).

Comment: These _actualLeft and _actualTop fields should be used only when a window in the maximized state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
    WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow);
    Screen screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(windowInteropHelper.Handle);
```

The Screen Bounds property provides the coordinates of the whole window and the WorkingArea the boundaries of the area without titlebar and docked windows.

Comment: I went with your answer because it creates less overhead than @Corentin Pane 's answer, I am already referencing System.Window.Forms and need to check the position only once and not track the window or anything. Now I only check the screen bounds if the `Application.Current.MainWindow` is in state maximized, otherwise i use the MainWindow itself. Works like a charme now. Thanks to you both for your help.

Comment: @kirbby yeah I didn't realize tracking was not required:)

Comment: I didn't mention it explicitly in the post, your answer is better if you need tracking, that's why I upvoted your answer aswell, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `win32` API to retrieve the information you want as the events exposed by .NET aren't enough to detect this scenario.

There are two things you have to do:

1. Listen to the `WndProc` message that corresponds to a window movement (full list [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html)). The one we want is `WM_MOVE` and is equal to `0x0003`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf) for details.
2. Be able to determine the real location of the `Window` even when it's in `Maximized` state, which we can do by using the `GetWindowRect` method. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425884/c4-0-getwindowrect-in-wpf) for details.

Here would be the assembled code that prints the top-left location of your `Window` when it is moved, including using the shortcut you describe.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    HwndSource source;

    const short WM_MOVE = 0x0003;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Loaded event needed to make sure the window handle has been created.
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Subscribe to win32 level events
        source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
        if (msg == WM_MOVE) {
            Console.WriteLine("Window has moved!");
            GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle), out RECT rect);
            Console.WriteLine("New location is " + (rect.Left, rect.Top));
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
}
```